# Performing selective operation on R data frame without loop

Tags: r, plyr

I have this data frame

```
|    A    |    B    |    C    | Output |
|---------|---------|---------|--------|
| NoFault | NoFault | NoFault |   8    |
|  Fault  | NoFault | NoFault |   2    |
| NoFault |  Fault  | NoFault |   0    |
|  Fault  |  Fault  | NoFault |   2    |
| NoFault | NoFault |  Fault  |   2    |
|  Fault  | NoFault |  Fault  |   0    |
| NoFault |  Fault  |  Fault  |   2    |
|  Fault  |  Fault  |  Fault  |   4    |
```

I have generated this using the following code:

```
A <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
B <- c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0)
C <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
Output <- c(8,2,0,2,2,0,2,4)
data <- data.frame(cbind(A,B,C,Output))
```

I wish to perform an operation to calculate the percentage of output for column C and the result should look like this:

```
|    A    |    B    |    C    | Output |
|---------|---------|---------|--------|
| NoFault | NoFault | NoFault |8/(8+2) |
|  Fault  | NoFault | NoFault |2/(2+0) |
| NoFault |  Fault  | NoFault |0/(0+2) |
|  Fault  |  Fault  | NoFault |2/(2+4) |
| NoFault | NoFault |  Fault  |2/(2+8) |
|  Fault  | NoFault |  Fault  |0/(0+2) |
| NoFault |  Fault  |  Fault  |2/(2+0) |
|  Fault  |  Fault  |  Fault  |4/(4+2) |
```

So, what's happening here is that whenever I'm getting column A,B sequence repeated I'm taking those rows and making their output in percentage.

For example `A = NoFault`, `B=NoFault`, Convert the output for C `Fault` & `NoFault` into fraction
I wish to perform this using vector operations or `plyr` package if loop can be avoided.

Comment: Please copy the output of `dput(yourdataframe)` into the question. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I don't understand the role of C, can you illustrate on a few more rows?

Comment: Please show us what code you have already written. We are here to help correct broken code, not to write it for you. Thanks.

Comment: So, it is like whenever A & B are some values (Fault/NoFault) then what are the chances of getting C as Fault or NoFault.

Therefore, row 1 & 5 constitute one case. Similarly, row 2 & 6 as second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a new column (or a temporary variable, if you prefer), with the total.  Then use that to get the percentage.

```
data$Total <- ave(Output, A, B, FUN=sum)
data$Percent <- data$Output/data$Total
data

##   A B C Output Total   Percent
## 1 1 1 1      8    10 0.8000000
## 2 0 1 1      2     2 1.0000000
## 3 1 0 1      0     2 0.0000000
## 4 0 0 1      2     6 0.3333333
## 5 1 1 0      2    10 0.2000000
## 6 0 1 0      0     2 0.0000000
## 7 1 0 0      2     2 1.0000000
## 8 0 0 0      4     6 0.6666667
```